# Undeclared variable with LESS @import. What is causing this? Is there a fix?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less

I have 2 LESS files. Globals.less and Site.less. Globals.less contains all of my global (go figure) variables and an import to a CSS reset definition. Site.less contains the styles in use.

Globals.less:

```
//Imports
@import "CSSReset.less";

//Colors
@color-background: rgb(0, 0 , 0);
```

Site.less:

```
@import "Globals.less";

body {
    background: @color-background url('/Images/BackgroundTextureBody.png');
}
```

The problem is this: In Visual Studio @color-background in Site.less is underlined and the error is "Undeclared variable", but the LESS compiles to CSS just fine and the background color is properly set to #000. It is more of an annoyance than anything, but I lose Intellisense and I get warnings in my error list. I would like the editor to act as expected and be able to "see" my declarations in Globals.less when I am editing Site.less. Am I doing something wrong, is this a bug, or is my environment not setup correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was using an older version of Web Essentials 2012. The first thing I should have checked and failed to do was to ensure that my environment was up to date. Updating Web Essentials to the latest version corrected the issue.

Answer (score 10):

To get intellisense for a particular less file you can add a reference path in the same way you would to get intellisense in a js file.

**Example**

```
/// <reference path="Globals.less" />

@import "Globals.less";

body {
    background: @color-background url('/Images/BackgroundTextureBody.png');
}
```

Comment: For some reason this just refuses to work for me. I've got the standard VS bootstrap install, attempting to use /// <reference path="bootstrap/variables.less" /> and it refuses to get rid if the undeclared variables problem. Below that are my bootstrap.less and theme.less @imports. Version 2.2.

Comment: I've narrowed this down to the '|' character in this line: @import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans|Roboto"); Looks like a bug in 2.2. Remove "|Roboto", save, reload, and intellisense works!

Comment: This mostly works for me. However, I still see the error logs in the Error list  output tab.

Comment: This worked for me when I wanted to use variables in a mixin LESS file without actually importing the variable definitions. Instead, variables and mixins would later both be imported to a bootstrap file. Setting the `<reference path=.../>` comment made intellisense accept this approach.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Visual Studio (or it's LESS interpreter) does not understand the scope of the variable within the imported Globals.less

Importing variables is a normal and common thing to do so I'd suggest that it's a bug or missing feature in your Visual Studio setup.