# Bootstrap Less Variables in VS2013 - Fails Intellisense and Undeclared Variable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, visual-studio-2013, less, web-essentials

Why doesn't Intellisense work for the Bootstrap less variables?

The problem is this: The `@gray`, and any other variable in `variables.less`, which is referenced inside `bootstrap.less`, is underlined with "Undeclared variable" error, but the LESS compiles to CSS as expected and the color is properly set to #555555.

As said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790807/undeclared-variable-with-less-import-what-is-causing-this-is-there-a-fix), it's more an annoyance than a problem, since Intellisense is lost and every variable must be typed and remembered without the help from Intellisense.

Unlike the question mentioned above, I'm using VS2013 and Web Essentials 2013, both were updated today, but the problem still occurs.

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

**Less Code**

```
// _MasterLayout.LESS

@import "/bootstrap/bootstrap.less";

@header-height: 120px;
@footer-height: 240px;

html {
    height: 100%;
    color: @gray;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    height: @header-height;

// ...
```

**CSS Generated Code**

```
...

html {
  height: 100%;
  color: #555555;
}

...
```

Comment: Bootstrap makes use of advanced and "bleeding edge" Less features. Visual Studio simply can't parse the files, so it breaks down. And until Less stabilizes (on syntax and/or semantics) I wouldn't expect it to be able to deal with these giant style frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the compilation was ok, I don't know why Intellisense was failing with the given code, but, the following solution will fix it.

Considering the following files structure:

```
 - Content
   - bootstrap
     - bootstrap.less
     - variables.less
     - anythingelse.less
   - master.less
```

Instead of import with a `/` before bootstrap folter:

```
// _MasterLayout.LESS

@import "/bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
```

Import without the `/` before bootstrap folder:

```
// _MasterLayout.LESS

@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a reference path to your less file.  This works in the same way as it would in a js file by giving you intellisense for that file.

So for your case you will need to reference the bootstrap variables.less file.

**Example**

```
// _MasterLayout.LESS

/// <reference path="/bootstrap/variables.less" />

html {
    color: @grey; // Should have intellisense now.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't works also... :(

Comment: The good news, is that I solved it! :) I'll post the answer right now!